# COUNTING the number of DISTINCT rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I'm building a commenting system with PHP/MySQL. This commenting system has a nice feature, which allows users to highlight text (stored as "selected_text" in the database) and that highlighted text will then be stored in the database with the comment the user made. Additionally, I am also storing the paragraph (of which the highlighted text appeared), as an INT. These values are all storing properly in the database, but now I want to do something with them.

**I want to create "comment counters."** These comment counters will be placed next to each paragraph in the article, and they will display the total number of comments that were made on that paragraph to which they are attached. The visual overview of the "comments": table structure:

[image: This is a view of the table structure]

My latest query to attempt to retrieve this information is:

`$distinct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT paragraph_id) FROM comments");`

And the corresponding PHP code:

```
while ($result_three = mysql_fetch_array($distinct)) 
{ 
    echo $result_three['paragraph_id'];
}
```

Now, I think I may be going about this the wrong way. I have considered attempting to run a query that first finds all of the `DISTINCT paragraph_ids`. Following that, I would run a *for each* loop that counts the number of times those `paragraph_ids` appear.

The query I am working with right now does not seem to achieve my goal. Also, I am worried that there isn't a clear way for me to distinctly attach the counted data to a "comment counter."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to count the comments in each group of paragraph ids.  The correct query is below:

```
$distinct = mysql_query("SELECT paragraph_id, (DISTINCT comment_id) as comment_count FROM comments GROUP BY paragraph_id");

while ($result_three = mysql_fetch_array($distinct)) 
{ 
    echo $result_three['paragraph_id']; // Gives the id of the paragraph
    echo $result_three['comment_count']; // Gives the comment count for the associated paragraph
}
```

Comment: This is correct, too. I tried to answer my own question with the additional PHP code, but it won't let Stack Overflow newbs like me do that for 8 hours after posting the question! :)  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to `GROUP BY paragraph_id`. Try this:

```
SELECT paragraph_id, COUNT(*)
FROM comments
GROUP BY paragraph_id
```

Comment: This is close. It counts the number of unique paragraph_ids. The value it prints out is 3. Not quite what I'm looking for. I am trying to retrieve something like this: for every paragraph_id that is unique, count the total number of comments that were made on that paragraph_id.

Comment: No, it will return the number of comments (rows on `comments` table) that mention each `paragraph_id`. Run this on phpMyAdmin to see what I mean.

Comment: My gosh, sorry, you are right. My apologies. I was getting a different result when using the PHP. I think the problem was that I wasn't referring to the right key from the fetch_array. What ended up working for me was combining a few answers, and ultimately calling an alias. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Use below code, this should work

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT paragraph_id) as cnt FROM comments");

while ($result_three = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { echo $result_three['cnt']; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Its likely that you want to also know when there are *zero* comments you'll need to do an outer join to paragraphs.

```
SELECT p.paragraph_id,
       COUNT(c.comment_id) as comment_count 
FROM   comments c 
       RIGHT JOIN paragraphs p 
         ON c.paragraph_id = p.paragraph_id 
GROUP  BY p.paragraph_id
```

here's a working [data.se sample](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60495/sample-for-9068932)

Comment: This is the winner. I ended up modifying this code by excluding the JOIN components, and included an "AS" before comment_count. 

What I then had to echo to in the PHP was 
`echo $result=['comment_count'];`

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, was a great baseline to build my query from, cheers